# How to use POI SXSSFWorkbook export more than 65535 row data?

Tags: apache-poi

as excel 2003(.xls) support 65536 rows data and 256 columns
excel 2007(.xlsx) support 1048576 rows data and 16384 columns
when we need to export the data more than 65536, then we need to use .xlsx

Comment: below is work code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
package com.lux.poi_excel;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class ExportExcelRowThan65535 {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = null;
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\aaa.xlsx");
            bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            //load template         
            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);

            SXSSFWorkbook wb = new SXSSFWorkbook(workbook,100);
            //get template sheet
            Sheet sheet = wb.getXSSFWorkbook().getSheetAt(0);
            //get template sheet head row
            Row headRow = wb.getXSSFWorkbook().getSheetAt(0).getRow(0);
            for(int i=1;i<100000;i++) {
                Row newRow = sheet.createRow(i);
                newRow.createCell(0).setCellValue("a");
            }
            
            wb.write(bos);
            bos.writeTo(new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\bbb.xlsx"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            try {
                fis.close();
                bos.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Done");
        
    }

}
```

Comment: Why use `ByteArrayOutputStream bos`? - write to `fos` directly - and you must call `fos.close()`. See this example: https://github.com/pjfanning/poi-shared-strings-sample/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/pjfanning/poi/sample/StreamingWrite.java

Comment: yes, you are right , i will update my sample code later.